# Correct Setting for cx_Oracle.Cursor.bindarraysize

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm finding some conflicting documentation on what the correct setting for the `Cursor.bindarraysize` attribute in cx_Oracle.

[cx-oracle.readthedocs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.bindarraysize) says

> This read-write attribute specifies the number of rows to bind at a time and is used when creating variables via setinputsizes() or var(). It defaults to 1 meaning to bind a single row at a time.

[Documentation for the database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-0ADAEFB5-43F2-444A-8A8F-3A82A03ED019.htm#SUTIL1138) describes the Bind Array Size differently:

> The bind array's size is equivalent to the number of rows it contains times the maximum length of each row. The maximum length of a row equals the sum of the maximum field lengths, plus overhead, as follows:

I tend to believe the former, since it's possible that the Python API is doing that computation when you call `Cursor.setinputsizes` but can someone confirm or disconfirm that belief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cx_Oracle documentation is correct with respect to how cx_Oracle works. This value specifies the number of rows that can be bound at a single time. The value 1 is appropriate for all cases except where executemany() is being called. I have considered removing this value since you can specify the size when you create a variable anyway (using the parameter arraysize), and if you don't do so, it will automatically resize the variable anyway when it detects multiple rows are being bound.